# Substitute for celery in soup

Tags: substitutions, soup, resources, celery

I'm making this [Creamy Chicken and Mushroom Soup](http://damndelicious.net/2015/01/10/creamy-chicken-mushroom-soup/) recipe and I wanted to know what can I use as a substitute for celery because it'll be difficult to get it before tonight.

Comment: Daikon, cut to correct size and cooked a bit, but not enough to be soggy might work. You want a mild variety, not something radishy hot, just a neutral "I bit into a slightly crunchy vegetable" feel. Celery is not flavorless, but it does not stand up and shout "TASTE ME, for I am CELERY!!!" either.

Comment: Celery is boring enough that you can leave it out without missing much.

Answer (score 8):

Honestly, I'd say there is no substitute that you're likely to have on hand. The unique qualities of celery are mostly the cellulose crunch it provides, and the suggested substitutions like daikon, radish, bok choy or the like are even less likely to be in your pantry.

Most likely you'll just have to go without or make a trip.

If it is *just* the taste in that recipe you're going for, you could use celery seed if you happen to have that on hand.

Reference:  http://www.thekitchn.com/my-celery-dilemma-154426

Comment: Agreed...but for me celery is perhaps the most important flavor component part of a good veg broth.